# How to Pass Variable Into .post()?

Tags: javascript, jquery, function, variables, scope

I have something like this...

```
$().ready(function () {

    $(".post .comment_this").click(function () {

        var comment_id = $(this).attr('rel');

        $.post(url_base + 'bio/community/get_comments', { 'comment_id' : comment_id }, function (response) {

            console.log(comment_id);

        });

    });

});
```

How to pass `comment_id` into that function? So I can use it there...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use it there without a problem.

In Javascript you can access every variable defined in the scope chain, up to the global scope. Locally defined variables will override the ones that come from the chain.

[JavaScript Variable Scope on SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/500431/javascript-variable-scope)

Answer (score 0):

Should be fine:

```
<button id="go">Go!</button>
<div id="TestDiv">dd</div>

$("#go").live('click', function(e) {
    alert("win");
    var TestVar = "Message :)";
    $("#TestDiv").load("http://www.ryth.net/", function () {
        alert(TestVar);
    });
});
```

> http://jsfiddle.net/EDx3A/1/